# Change whether file is executable

Tags: beginner, objective-c, file-system, osx

This is a cocoa app that adds a right click menu option to change whether a file is executable. It works by executing the system command `chmod` on each of the files. But I want to know if there is a better way to change the permission of a file, such as a cocoa function that can change the permission of a file.

What are some other ways that I can improve my code?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();
}
void runSystemCommand(NSString *cmd)
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/chmod"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isExecutableFileAtPath:cmd]) {
        //NSLog(@"is executable \n");
        [task setArguments:@[ @"-x", cmd]];
        [task launch];

    } else {
        //NSLog(@"is not executable \n");
        [task setArguments:@[ @"+x", cmd]];
        [task launch];

    }
}
- (void)handleServices:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
              userData:(NSString *)userData
                 error:(NSString **)error {
    if([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]){
        NSArray* fileArray=[pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        int i;
        int count;
        count = [fileArray count];
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
            //NSLog (@"%@", [fileArray objectAtIndex: i]);
            runSystemCommand([fileArray objectAtIndex: i]);
        }
    }
}

@end
```

[Here](https://github.com/kylelk/Toggle-Executable) is the repository for the complete project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant `NSFileManager` call, in Foundation, is `- setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`, and it is the same in [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes%3aofItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) as in [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes%3aofItemAtPath%3aerror%3a).  (It's funny that you already call `- isExecutableFileAtPath:` in the same `NSFileManager` class.)  Even if you weren't familiar with Foundation, you would still be better off calling the POSIX function [`chmod(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html) rather than the [`chmod(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) command.

You've neglected to do any kind of error handling on the `/bin/chmod` task.  The operation could easily fail if, for example, the user did not have permission to modify the file.

It's misleading to name the parameter of `runSystemCommand()` `cmd`, as it really only contains the path to the file whose permissions are to be toggled.